# Need to access multiple @XmlRootElement in a XML - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-batch

Let's say I have an XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results application="web" hostname="WIN">
    <test-node>
        <element>1</element>
    </test-node>
    <node1 browser="chrome">
        <element2>2</element2>
    </node1>
</results>
```

I want to write most of the attributes in this XML to a MySql Database using Spring Batch. So I created a class that looks like below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "results")
public class LowLevelSuiteFields {

private String application;
private String hostName;

@XmlAttribute(name = "application")
public String getApplication() {
    return application;
}

public void setApplication(String application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "hostname")
public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
}

public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

}
```

The question is I also want to access the attribute `browser` in `node1`. I can't have another `@XmlRootElement(name = "node1")` and then do a `@XmlAttribute(name = "browser")`

The reason is I'm only creating one `PreparedStatementSetter` that implements `ItemPreparedStatementSetter<LowLevelSuiteFields>`... So I can't create another class just for another `XmlRootElement`

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should use the `@XmlElement` annotation for your element `node1`.

Have a look for example to this [JAXB tutorial from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html)